# Permission Denied When Deleting Java Files Through Terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I'm trying to delete some .java files using Terminal in my Mac's /Library/Java/Extensions folder. Currently, I see this in my terminal when searching for the folder:

```
my-air:~ my$ ls /Library/Java/Extensions/
logback-classic.jar slf4j-api.jar
logback-core.jar    xuggle-xuggler.jar
```

I want to delete all four files in the folder. When I try to delete the files individually using `rm -Rf /Library/Java/Extensions/logback-classic.jar`
I get an error saying "Permission Denied". I also tried `sudo rm -R`What command should I be using to delete them?

Comment: What was the output after running the `sudo` command?  You will certainly need it since that directory does not belong to your user.

Comment: Update the output of "ls -le"